# Mongoid update association with existing documents, not creating a new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm attempting to figure out how to elegantly update a document's associations with existing documents with Mongoid.

If I have Users and Groups, and want to assign a User to an existing group, how could I do this via update_attributes ?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
user.attributes = { groups: [{"_id":"existing group id here"}]}
user.save
```

When I try to do the above, Mongoid attempts to INSERT a new group, thereby causing a ID duplicate error. 
I have tried doing the same via nested attributes:

```
user.groups_attributes = [{"_id":"existing group id here"}]
user.save
```

And the same error occurs. Is there anyway I can do this WITHOUT having to manually query the group id and push it into the array? The reason I'm asking is because lets say i have a model with many associations.. i dont want to have to have blocks of code to update each association manually

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an an existing User to an existing Group with `update_attributes` is very simple (assuming you already added the Group/User relation).

```
user.update_attributes(:group_id => 'existing group id here')
```